# Using lambda to call a function n number of times (python)

Tags: python

Can someone walk me through, if possible, how I would use the lambda function in Python to call a function n number of times?

Like I have a function

```
def repeat_lam(a, n):
    lambda x: f(x)
```

I want to run `a`, `n` times on `x`. I'm not sure how to edit my current code to make it do this.

So if i had a function that was defined to multiply by 2 called `mul_2`.

```
repeat_lam(mul_2,3)(10)
80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried but to no avail. Will update OP right now.

Comment: To do something a number of times, you need to use a for-loop or recursion. That has nothing to do with lambdas. So it's not clear what you _really_ want to do.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but I've just started programming. But, is there a way that doesn't involve recursion to make the repeat_lam function in the OP do something n number of times. Can you expand on the forloop?

Comment: If you had just started programing, and is usign Python, stay away from lambda's -- at least for a month or two. They are a 100% optional feature for anything you ant to achieve aand code without it, thought a bit longer, is far easier to understand.

Comment: You seem to be confused. `lambda` is not how you "do something with" a function. It's how you create a short, one-off function that you can "do something with" (in your case, apply multiple times).

Answer (score 4):

So our specification is:

```
>>> repeat_lam(mul_2,3)(10)
80
```

This setup requires that `mul_2` is a function, which we can define using a `lambda` if we want. I will show that, but it isn't really needed. The implementation of `repeat_lam` will have nothing to do with lambdas. It will, however, need to be a function... that returns a function (so that we can call the result with `(10)`.

```
def repeat_lam(func, times):
    def wrapper(arg):
        for i in range(times):
            arg = func(arg)
        return arg
    return wrapper
```

We define a function that is nested inside `repeat_lam` - in Python, functions are objects, so they can be treated like any other object. That means, among other things, that we can return it :) So what happens here is that `wrapper` refers to the `func` and `times` values that were passed in to `repeat_lam`. To support this, Python will return a separate object each time `repeat_lam` is called - each one will be a function, and each one will be "named" `wrapper`, but they get separate `func` and `times` values bound to them, through some internal Python magic (in technical terms, Python creates a *closure*).

So when you call the returned function, it will automatically use the `func` and `times` values that were passed in when `repeat_lam` was called, along with the `arg` passed in for the call. The rest of that code is straightforward: we apply `func` repeatedly to `arg`, assigning back to `arg` to build up the results, and then we return it.

And now we can test it (and see how lambda is used):

```
>>> mul_2 = lambda x: x * 2
>>> repeat_lam(mul_2,3)(10)
80
```

The effect of the lambda is the same as:

```
>>> def mul_2(x):
...     return x * 2
```

but lambdas can only evaluate a single expression, so they are more limited in scope than full-fledged functions. The main purpose for them is when the task is so simple that you don't even want to bother naming it:

```
>>> repeat_lam(lambda x: x * 2, 3)(10)
80
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple, straightforward approach:

```
def exec_num_times(f,times,*args,**kwargs):
  for _ in range(times):
      f(*args,**kwargs)
```

There are other ways too. For example if you have a function, and then a list of arguments:

`results = [f(x) for x in list_of_args]`

However, that is not necessary as you can simply pass `list_of_args` directly to `f()`; as Python methods [take variable list of arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and you should not normally rely on a method being passed a particular *type* of variable. It should be flexible enough to work with any type.

Comment: Based on the example in the OP, I think he specifically wants to support functions in 1 parameter, and to treat that parameter as an accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a lambda function, something like this:

```
ntimes = lambda f, args, n: (f(*args), ntimes(f, args, n-1)) if n>1 else (f(*args),)

def foo(bar):
    print "foo", bar
ntimes(foo, ["bar"], 10)
```

In this case, the return value would be a tuple of the return values of the individual calls.

If you want the return value of the first call to be fed into the second call, and so on, you yould use a lambda function like this:

```
ntimes2 = lambda f, arg, n: ntimes2(f, f(arg), n-1) if n>1 else f(arg)
```

However, the simplest way to apply a function n times would be to use a for-loop, not to use a lambda function.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without recursion?

Comment: You can simply use a loop, but not inside a lambda function.

Comment: That's not a recursive lambda. Recursive lambda is what you construct with Y-combinator.

Answer (score 0):

For the nature of your question, it is possible you are trying to adapt a technique used in functional programing that avoids "loops" alltogether, replacing those with function calls.

So, instead of relying on a simple language construct as we have in empiric languages to repeat a statement over and over which would be:

```
repeats = 10
result = 0
for i in range(repeats):
    result = function(result)
```

Instead of this, you can create a function that receives two parameters, the second being 
a counter, the first the intermediate result - if the counter value is 0, it simply returns the intermediate result. Else, it calls the original function with the intermediate result, and calls *itself* again, but with the counter diminished by 1:

```
def repeat_func(function, result, repeat):
    if repeat == 0:
        return result
    return repeat_func(function, function(result), repeat - 1)
```

In earlier times when learning programming, some people preferred this approach - but it is obviously more complicated. If whatever material you have to study is suggesting things like this, it is important that you find another source to study.